# Serial voting was reversed? Static or relative threshold?

Tags: support, votes

I read one answer that stated not to ask about this on the meta site, within 48 hours. But I don't know how else to contact a moderator. And also I think it might be a bug.

I lost 35 reputation points last week, without a known reason, just with the message "Serial voting was reversed". I read something about voting fraud, which I'm not aware off. I did got -35 points at a moment where I asked several questions in quite a short timespan.

Is it possible that the amount of "up votes by the same user" are not relative to the amount of recent questions but a static "low" threshold that could cause the anti-voting fraud script to reverse the votes because it flags it as "one user upvoting another user too much in a short time?".

*As far as I know, I don't know anybody on this site personally and won't see a reason why anybody would upvote my questions or answers suddenly a lot.*

*Also, the lack of information is a bit annoying. I don't know what user did so, I also don't know on which of my questions or answers this is flagged.*

Can someone look into it please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the serial voting detection mechanisms see something that identifies as serial voting (up or down) the votes will be reversed. The reversal is done as part of an automated process and data is not provided on who the individual (or voting ring) was or which posts were voted on.

(Sorry we cannot give any detail of the serial vote detection process)

As to why - sometimes there is no reason. Sometimes someone saw a good post and checked out that user's other posts and upvote. Loads of possible reasons. It's usually not worth worrying about them though, as serial votes are a blip that should be removed. I know it's a bit concerning if you suddenly lose some rep (as opposed to suddenly gain some by a vote reversal) but remember - it's not you, it's them :-)